# When transaction is finalized in HLF v1?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

According to architecture explained (http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/arch-deep-dive.html), ordering service collects transactions (RWSets) into block for distribution to committing peers. Then, committing peer validates endorsement policy and RWsets then apply the transaction to ledger.

To verify the transaction was succeeded, should client application wait until all committing peers returned "Success" event ? Or just need to verify only one "Success" event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To verify the transaction was succeeded, should client application
>   wait until all committing peers returned "Success" event ? Or just
>   need to verify only one "Success" event ?

Tanaka, that's a very good question!
The short answer is **No**.

The reason is that in contrast to existing popular blockchains, HLF has a unique transaction lifecycle which does:

- A transaction is simulated on some endorser or a few endorsers
- It is sent to the ordering service and is cut into some block
- The block is sent to peers, and they all execute **the same validation code** and all validation code for a specific transaction is guaranteed to reach the same conclusion in all peers, because they run it in the same order across all of them.

Therefore, if a transaction is validated on some peer - when other peers will receive the block the transaction resides in - they will too consider it as valid.

However - a very important aspect you should consider is data availability and synchronization.
For example, if you have an application that uses 10 peers and only 1 peer got the event and the rest didn't, and you invoke another transaction on the other peers, it might be that the endorsements that the other peers will compute will be turned into an invalid transaction, because they will simulate on old data (the fact that they didn't get the event yet proves that they have not processed the block for that transaction), so you need to keep that in mind.

Comment: Thank you very much for very nice explanation. That's really what I'd like to confirm. Now I'm very clear about transaction finality of Fabric.